# How to Install Bootstrap Theme in Wagtal

Tags: themes, wagtail

Does anyone here have link on how to install a startboostrap theme in Wagtail

Comment: Is your question about programming? please kindly learn how to ask good question for this https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look at:

1. https://blog.michaelyin.info/wagtail-tutorials-6-import-theme-wagtail-blog/
2. https://github.com/moorinteractive/wagtail-themes (This one is a bit dated but looks very promising if you can get it to work with 2.x )